# Как определить количество записей с id - номером и сколько id используются в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Суть вопроса такова, что у меня есть таблица с id-номером покупателей и id-номер товара. Мне нужно создать запрос mysql, так, чтобы на каждый id покупателя выводилось общее количество товара. id покупателя может повторяться несколько раз.
Заранее благодарен.

**Обновление**

count подсчитывает общее количество элементов. Может я не правильно выразился. Суть

```
a[0]=5  
a[1]=5   
a[2]=6  
a[3]=8  
a[4]=5  
------- производим запрос и получаем массив ----  
b[0]=5  
b[1]=6  
b[2]=8
```

Есть ли такой запрос в mysql?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id_user, count(*) cnt from table group by id_product
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Может быть DISTINCT?

Comment: раньше я создавал массив всех значений, а потом перебирал по одному и проверял есть ли такое значение в новом массиве, если есть, то пропускал, если нет, то добавлял.